Why doesn't `randrange(start=100)` raise an error?
In the docs for randrange(), it states:

Keyword arguments should not be used because they can be interpreted in unexpected ways. For example randrange(start=100) is interpreted as randrange(0, 100, 1).

If the signature is random.randrange(start, stop[, step]), why doesn't randrange(start=100) raise an error, since stop is not passed a value?
Why would randrange(start=100) be interpreted as randrange(0, 100, 1)?
I'm not trying to understand the design choice of whoever wrote the code, so much as understanding how it's even possible.  I thought parameters without default values need to be passed arguments or else a TypeError would be raised.

My Python version shows randrange(start, stop=None, step=1, _int=<class 'int'>) in the implementation.  But note that with a single argument, start actually becomes stop.

A single parameter passed to range() or similar functions is interpreted as the stop value, not the start.  This is handled by special-casing inside the function, it's not something that can be expressed in the function's parameter list.

But if the single parameter is supposed to be stop=100, but is named start=100, shouldn't that raise an error?

help output: randrange(start, stop=None, step=1) method of random.Random instance    Choose a random item from range(stop) or range(start, stop[, step]).

The first parameter is named start, whether you pass it positionally or via keyword.  It's just interpreted as stop, if no actual stop parameter was given.

@jasonharper, I see.  Reading the source code linked in the answer posted helped clear that up for me.  Seeing random.randrange(start, stop[, step]) in the docs made me think that stop did not have a default value.  I see now that it does.  I guess I don't understand why the docs don't show the actual signature.

@Joe, if the docs would show it as random.randrange(start[, stop, step]) then how would you know which signature would be used when you call randrange(100)? The documentation is correct in this point, and what you see in the code, is the implementation necessary to support the two signatures.

@trincot, I guess it's not possible, due to Python not allowing parameters without defaults after parameters with defaults. Otherwise I'd say the signature is random.randrange(start=0, stop, step=1). Is that why there are two "signatures" shown?

Given that there are two signatures, I'm just surprised that the "special-casing" doesn't use one positional parameter as stop, but raise an error for (start=100). Is the reason that it doesn't raise an error to increase speed?

As to your suggestion for random.randrange(start=0, stop, step=1): you could put it like that, but that signature is ambiguous; for instance when you call randrange(2, 2): are those the values for start/stop, or for stop/step?

@trincot, yes, I suppose it is ambiguous without a well-defined algorithm for how the arguments would be parsed.  I imagined that any call would need at least as many arguments passed as there were parameters without defaults, and that if there were more than that passed, they would be passed in their order in the signature, so that e.g.  def f(a=0, b, c=2, d, e=4, f): when called with f(6,7,8,9) would be interpreted as a=6, b=7, d=8, f=9. But I know in Python that's not possible.

This is because the code for randrange must also support the alternative signature:
random.randrange(stop)

The implementation performs a check to see whether the call uses this signature or the other one:
random.randrange(start, stop[, step])

It does so with this code:
    istart = _index(start)
    if stop is None:
        if istart > 0:
            return self._randbelow(istart)

This makes sense when you call randrange(100), where it translates into a call of _randbelow(100), which is intended.
But when you call randrange(start=100), then we get into the same flow, and the value of start is also interpreted as stop.
